# SSL certificate acceptable by browsers

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, https, lamp

I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial to setup HTTPS on AWS Ubuntu LAMP. I needed it to create Facebook canvas app. When ever someone else tries to load that app they get `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` error.

Apeearantly Chrome and Edge don't deem my certificate trustworthy. Why is it? Can it be because I misspelled some info or do certificates have to issued by a thrid party?

Comment: Did you read the note ?

Comment: Learn more about generating SSL Certificates from third party sites -  https://in.godaddy.com/help/generating-a-csr-and-installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-tomcat-4x5x6x7x-5239

Comment: Insn't it godaddy/tomcat/Java specific?

Comment: @EdmundSulzanok "Note: You may want to consider using Let's Encrypt instead of a self-signed certificate. " "You will get a warning that your browser cannot verify the identity of your server because it has not been signed by one of the certificate authorities that it trusts." "it will warn each user that the browser cannot verify the validity of the certificate." "If you are planning on launching a public site and need SSL, you will be better off purchasing an SSL certificate from a trusted certificate authority."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a self-signed certificate. It hasn't been signed by anyone in the chain of trust that ends up with the organisations that have certificates embedded into the browser or OS.

This is covered in detail in Step 5 of the tutorial you linked to.

> do certificates have to issued by a thrid party?

Either that or the user must explicitly mark the certificate as safe.

Answer (score 1):

There were two errors:
1) "wrong domain"
2) server's certificate is not trusted

As for the first one, I had provide a subdomain as well.

The second was solved by installing a free certificate by following instructions here https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/.

basically:

1. sudo apt-get install git
2. git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt
3. cd letsencrypt
4. ./letsencrypt-auto --help
5. ./letsencrypt-auto --apache

I'm in no way affiliated with this company other than becoming a user 5 mins ago.